# android - file uploading via android http server

Tags: android, forms, http, upload

*Hello*

I tried to upload files to android via HTTP server,

I have made HTML form to upload file, but how to receive that file to store in SDCard?

I am just receiving file's name, nothing else.

*How to receive that file?*

Comment: u wont get the file..u will get the file name only..pass the path to multipart

Comment: @sheetal how to pass that file to multi-part? I have already added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to html form.

Comment: use multipart libraries from Apache

Comment: @sheetal in my case, android is itself a server. and i want to receive that files sent through user using html form. any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
      MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
  entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));
  entity.addPart("data", new FileBody(new File(filepath));
  httppost.setEntity(entity);
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Than read the response
heres the reference [here](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/)

or use this sample without library multipart
[here](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void uploadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "Uploading " + file);
    String videoName = file.getParentFile().getName();

    AndroidHttpClient httpclient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(GoProLive.TAG);
    try {
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), ConnectTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), DataTimeout);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                String.format("http://" + ServerName + "/upload/%s/%s", user.getUsername(), file.getName()));
        post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file, "application/octet-stream"));

        SimpleDateFormat df = (SimpleDateFormat) SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT, SimpleDateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
        df.applyPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        post.setHeader("Last-Modified", df.format(new Date(file.lastModified())));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = executePost(httpclient, post);
        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            file.delete();
        } else {
            throw new HttpException("Failed to upload file " + file.getAbsolutePath(), statusCode);
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```